# Anyway to use NULL coalescing operator to simplify this code?

Tags: c#, null-coalescing-operator

I have this piece of code:

```
Phone addrFax = address.Phones.Phone.SingleOrDefault(p => p.PhoneType == PhoneTypeEnum.Fax);
if (addrFax != null)
    tba.Fax = addrFax.PhoneNumber;
```

It is repeated a number of times for various PhoneType values.  The whole thing is ugly.
I've been playing with the NULL coalescing operator (??) trying to simplify the code in the following manner, but it doesn't work.

```
tab.Fax = address.Phones.Phone.SingleOrDefault(p => p.PhoneType == PhoneTypeEnum.Fax).PhoneNumber ?? "";
```

Is there a way to convert what I have to a one-liner that's a bit easier to digest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the following?

```
tba.Fax = address.Phones.Phone.Where(p => p.PhoneType == PhoneTypeEnum.Fax)
                              .Select(p => p.Fax)
                              .SingleOrDefault() ?? string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do that yet, but monadic null checking is coming in C#6.  Then you can write

```
tab.Fax = address.Phones.Phone.SingleOrDefault(p => p.PhoneType == PhoneTypeEnum.Fax)?.PhoneNumber ?? "";
```

Notice the `?.` before `PhoneNumber`

Answer (score 1):

```
    Phone addrFax = address.Phones.Phone.Any(p => p.PhoneType == PhoneTypeEnum.Fax) ?
address.Phones.Phone.Single(p => p.PhoneType == PhoneTypeEnum.Fax).PhoneNumber : string.empty
```

Why don't you want to define a separate function?

```
Phone addrFax = GetPhone(address.Phones.Phone, PhoneTypeEnum.Fax)

public string GetPhone(PhoneTypeEnum phontype, IEnumerable<Phone> phones)
{
   return phones.Any(p => p.PhoneType == phontype) ? phones.Single(p => p.PhoneType == phontype).PhoneNumber : string.Empty;
}
```